# magento soap api to get all product details with filter php

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using magento 1.9.1 and I have to show my products on other website for that need api which give me list of all enable products with following details

- product id
- sku
- name
- description
- short description
- stock
- price
- tax
- category

So I need to call multiple magento api's, Is it possible in on api call?

Also I want products form specific category so filter is also needed

I have tried

```
$filter = array(
             'category_ids' => '59'
        );
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list',$filter);
```

But it gives list of all product

Comment: You would have to extend the existing api call/ write a new one to achieve this. There is no built in api to provide the above mentioned product details. For fetching list of products in a category you should use catalog_category.assignedProducts call. Ref : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.assignedProducts.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: If I directly made change in core api function info() and added my required detail in response then is it have any impact on existing website?

Comment: Usually API models changes doesn't affect website. But never edit magento core files. Create a local module following magento's documentation, It should be simple.

Comment: Ok,I have created same file in local and it works